# Problem with Docker- buid.sh: received: WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string

Tags: docker-compose, docker-build

I ve got a problem when running $ ./docker-build.sh I receive the following Warnings.

```
WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The HTTPS_HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The HTTP_HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The HTTPS_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The HTTP_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The LETSENCRYPT_MODE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The ADMIN_EMAIL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The POSTGRESQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The JENKINS_HTTP_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.jenkins.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.jenkins.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.geonode.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.geonode.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.jenkins.ports value [':', ':', '50000:50000'] has non-unique elements
```

My docker compose version is v2.5.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried running $ docker compose up -d. My docker compose version is v2.5.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. If I run the command: $ docker compose up -d I get the following Warnings:

```
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTPS_HOST" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTP_HOST" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTPS_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTP_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "LETSENCRYPT_MODE" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTP_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTPS_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTPS_HOST" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "HTTP_HOST" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "ADMIN_EMAIL" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "LETSENCRYPT_MODE" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "POSTGRESQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "JENKINS_HTTP_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "JENKINS_HTTP_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "JENKINS_HTTP_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
services.jenkins.ports array items[0,1] must be unique
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.10.2-buster
LABEL GeoNode development team

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/communalp

# Enable postgresql-client-13
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ buster-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -

# To get GDAL 3.2.1 to fix this issue https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1692
# TODO: The following line should be removed if base image upgraded to Bullseye
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list

# This section is borrowed from the official Django image but adds GDAL and others
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

# Prepraing dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libgdal-dev libpq-dev libxml2-dev \
    libxml2 libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev \
    libmemcached-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gcc zip gettext geoip-bin cron \
    postgresql-client-13 \
    sqlite3 spatialite-bin libsqlite3-mod-spatialite \
    python3-dev python3-gdal python3-psycopg2 python3-ldap \
    python3-pip python3-pil python3-lxml python3-pylibmc \
    uwsgi uwsgi-plugin-python3 \
    firefox-esr

RUN apt-get install -y devscripts build-essential debhelper pkg-kde-tools sharutils
# RUN git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian-gis-team/proj.git /tmp/proj
# RUN cd /tmp/proj && debuild -i -us -uc -b && dpkg -i ../*.deb

# Install pip packages
RUN pip install pip --upgrade \
    && pip install pygdal==$(gdal-config --version).* \
        flower==0.9.4

# Activate "memcached"
RUN apt install -y memcached
RUN pip install pylibmc \
    && pip install sherlock

# add bower and grunt command
COPY src /usr/src/communalp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/communalp

COPY src/monitoring-cron /etc/cron.d/monitoring-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/monitoring-cron
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/monitoring-cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN service cron start

COPY src/wait-for-databases.sh /usr/bin/wait-for-databases
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/wait-for-databases
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/communalp/tasks.py \
    && chmod +x /usr/src/communalp/entrypoint.sh

COPY src/celery.sh /usr/bin/celery-commands
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/celery-commands

COPY src/celery-cmd /usr/bin/celery-cmd
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/celery-cmd

# # Install "geonode-contribs" apps
# RUN cd /usr/src; git clone https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-contribs.git -b master
# # Install logstash and centralized dashboard dependencies
# RUN cd /usr/src/geonode-contribs/geonode-logstash; pip install --upgrade  -e . \
#     cd /usr/src/geonode-contribs/ldap; pip install --upgrade  -e .

RUN pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir  --src /usr/src -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade  -e .

# Cleanup apt update lists
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Export ports
EXPOSE 8000

# We provide no command or entrypoint as this image can be used to  enter code here`serve the django project or run celery tasks
# ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/communalp/entrypoint.sh
```

I'd be glad for any help. Thanks

Cheers Phil

Comment: Can you please share your Dockerfile/docker-compose.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am pretty new to docker so I hope I uploaded the correct file.

Comment: Is the `docker build` process working fine? You're copying local files, so I can't reproduce the error on my side. However I'm fairly certain that one of the tools you're trying to run is looking for all the ENV variables that are all labeled as `WARN`, however they don't seem to be defined within the container. You could check this by changing the CMD/Entrypoint to an abritary command to get a working shell open and check it yourself.

I think you're missing a file that contains all the desired ENV variables here.

Comment: Did u follow the instruction about how to create a geonode project?

Comment: I ran into some troubles that I couldn t figure out. So for now I leave that project as it is. Thanks for any help !

Comment: @Lockencharly While this could be a number of issues, check the format of your .env file. Env var values should be wrapped in 'single quotes' and NOT "double quotes". `DB_PASS='secret'`